# can't find the fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my code ... i cant find the fragment by tag

```
 transaction = getFragmentManager();
        transaction.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,tachoFrag,"m1");
        transaction.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,overviewFrag,"m2");
        transaction.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,dataLogFrag,"m3")
                .commit();

        tachoFrag = (menu1_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("m1");
        overviewFrag = (menu2_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("m2");
        dataLogFrag = (menu3_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("m3");


        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - transaction.replace(R.id.container, tachoFrag)");
        if (tachoFrag != null && tachoFrag.isVisible())
        {
            tachoFrag.setRevs(revs);
            tachoFrag.setSpeed(speed);
            tachoFrag.setFuelGauge(fuel);
            if(engTemp>60)
            {
                tachoFrag.setEngTemp(engTemp);
            }
            else
            {
                engTemp = 60;
                tachoFrag.setEngTemp(engTemp);
            }
            tachoFrag.setMileage(mileage);
            tachoFrag.setAmbientTemp(ambientTemp);
            tachoFrag.setGear(gear);

            transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, tachoFrag,"m1");
            transaction.beginTransaction().commit();
       }

       ...

        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - transaction.replace(R.id.container, dataLogFrag)");

            dataLogFrag.setData(time, speed, revs, gear);

            transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, dataLogFrag,"Data logger");
            transaction.beginTransaction().commit();
```

when i added the replace transaction to add a tag the second replace for the overviewfrag cause a null pointer issue ... please help

Comment: Please post the actual exception stack trace, including the line number reference. Makes it a lot easier to dissemble.

Comment: `transaction.beginTransaction().replace(...)` followed by `transaction.beginTransaction().commit()` gives you two transactions. The first transaction is never commited, the second one is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transaction.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,tachoFrag,"m1").commit(
        transaction.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,overviewFrag,"m2").commit();
```

You dont commited changes by first fragments.

Comment: i get this error at **Attempt to write to field 'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference** and it 's refering to the firs **transaction.beginTransaction()**

Comment: Emm.. Where you initialized fragments?

Comment: at the beginning of the class my Activity

'     public menu1_Fragment tachoFrag;
      public menu2_Fragment overviewFrag;
      public menu3_Fragment dataLogFrag;'

Comment: This does not initialize.
This definition.
You need initialized this fragments. like this `dataLogFrag = new menu3_Fragment ()`

Comment: Oh yess .... you are right i'm a beginner .... i did what u yold me about the initialization and the problem is solved

Comment: It's okay ;) Good luck )